# Meshlab: How do I select a specific point by typing x, y, z coordinate?

Tags: meshlab

I have a 3D measurement issue in Meshlab. I'm writing a C++ project to determined some specific points in human body. After running the script, I get some (x,y,z) coordinates of those points. Now I want to highlight those points in Meshlab to check if my code doing well. But I am new to Meshlab and I cannot find any tutorial about that. So can someone tell me how to do that?

Thank you and have a nice day ^^

Answer (score 3):

You could use the tool "conditional vertex selection", and use as expression "x==1.0 && y==1.0 && z==1.0" (assuming that the vertex you want to select is in position 1,1,1).
Then, you can enable the point shading and you will see all the selected vertices colored in red!